# How to treat a QString as a file location and get its directory

Tags: c++, qt

I gather a list of files into a QStringList from a Qt GUI.  Each of these files is a `.txt` file, with a corresponding video file in `same_folder_as_txt/videos/`.

Is there an easy way to manipulate QString objects as file paths?  For example, given `C:/some/path/foo.txt` , I want to retrieve `C:/some/path/videos/foo.avi`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert them each to `QDir`, perform your modifications as a path, and then use `absolutePath()` to get the `QString` back.

Answer (score 11):

Given your path as a `QString` `s`

```
info = QFileInfo(s)
// Get the name of the file without the extension
base_name = info.baseName()
// Add a ".avi" extension
video_file = QStringList((base_name, "avi")).join(".")
// Get the directory
dir_name = info.path()
// Construct the path to the video file
video_path = QStringList((dir_name, QString("videos"), video_file).join("/")
```

Comment: using QStringList to construct a path is a little bit like using light saber to open a tuna can. Why don't use concatenation operator? video_file = base_name % QLatin1String(".avi); and video_path = dir_name % QDir::separator() % QLatin1String("videos") % QDir::separator() % video_file;

Comment: @KamilKlimek This is bad advice.  [As the documentation clearly states](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdir.html#separator), QDir::separator() should not be used to build file paths.  The negligible benefits of appending your QStrings with the QStringBuilder concatenation operator (which you forgot to mention requires including <QStringBuilder>) are far outweighed by the non-portable code.